# Devexpress GroupFormat problem for DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, grouping, devexpress, datetime-format

I have a pretty simple question but can't find a way of resolving it. Pretty much i'm trying to group a DataTable by a column "Date" , which is a DateTime in the format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss". The display format for the column in my table is "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" and works correctly, but when grouping it shows only the day,month and year corretly, the hour and minutes being 00:00 for every value, even though when ungrouped the values are correct in the table. The group format is also set to the same "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" as the diplay format for the column and the type is set to DateTime for both. If anyone has any idea why this isn't working I would be greatful.

Comment: You presumably meant grouping in some control and not a datatable? Or mentioning DevExpress makes no sense. DevExpress has a gazillion of different controls that might or might not allow grouping. So we need to know about what control you are talking. And by the way DevExpress controls are typically payed. Here someone "might" know but the explicit DevExpress support "should" know especially if you payed for it.

Comment: The problem I'm encountering is happening in a GridControl.

Comment: Thats a starter and now what UI technology? Winforms, WPF, Blazor, Asp.Net etc?

Comment: Winforms and the version of the devexpress is 18.2

Comment: What do you use as [GroupInterval](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.GroupInterval)? According to the docu it presumably should be "Value".

Comment: That was it, it was set to Date and it only stored the current date without other time variables. Thank you!